# Close Flurl connection asap on POST

Tags: c#, flurl

How to close the connection asap when requests finish? Does Flurl close connection automatically on FlurResponse Dispose?

```
var fileContent = new FileContent("myfile");
using (var result = await url.WithHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream").PostAsync(fileContent))
                {
                   
                }
```

Comment: It's a more complicated topic than you might think, but to start I'd reframe your question (or better yet google it) around HttpClient. Flurl is just a light wrapper around that stack and adds nothing in the area of managing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own `FlurlClient` object, and call Dispose() or wrap it in a `using()`.

The way you're currently doing it, Flurl will create its own client.

> Flurl.Http adheres to this guidance by default. Fluent methods like this will create an `HttpClient` lazily, cache it, and reuse it for every call to the same host*:
>
> ```
> var data = await "http://api.com/endpoint".GetJsonAsync();
> ```

So instead, make your own

```
using (var client = new FlurlClient("mybaseurl"))
{
    // anything you want to do with it.
    await url
        .WithClient(client)
        // ... others
        .PostAsync();

    // or without the extension method
    await client
        .Request(url)
        // ... others
        .PostAsync();
}
```

See [the documentation about lifetime](https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/)